# Expanding Text Area throws error on Chrome/Firefox but not Safari

Tags: javascript

I have a text area that dynamically expands to fit the content inputed. It works correctly on all browsers, as far as I can tell, but on FireFox and Chrome it gives this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'height') at oninput`

Here's the code with an example:

```js
let ta = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

    for (let i = 0; i < ta.length; i++) {
        ta[i].setAttribute("style", "min-height:" + (ta[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
        ta[i].addEventListener("input", oninput, false);
    

    function oninput() {
        this.style.height = "auto";
        let maxheight = 200;
        if (this.scrollHeight < maxheight){
            this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
        }else{
            this.style.height = maxheight + "px";
        
    }
}

}
```

```html
<textarea>type here...</textarea>

<br><br>

<input type="text" placeholder="This should not be affected">
```

I would like this code to run smoothly on all platforms. Additionally I want to make sure I am only targeting `textarea` and not `input`, as the error presents if I change a normal input as well.

Comment: Move `function oninput() {` outside of your for loop. When it's inside of your for loop you're creating a function within a block, which ends up making things behave strangely, most likely due to web-compat semantics.

Comment: @NickParsons - that was it! dumb typo on my end.

Comment: @NickParsons - changed code back just so people can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function name with `onInput`, Or stop event propagation

```js
  function oninput(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation()
    // ... your code here
  }
```

The code you wrote above will be converted to below(I guess)

```js
let ta = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

    for (let i = 0; i < ta.length; i++) {
oninput = function() {
        this.style.height = "auto";
        let maxheight = 200;
        if (this.scrollHeight < maxheight){
            this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
        }else{
            this.style.height = maxheight + "px";
        
    }

        ta[i].setAttribute("style", "min-height:" + (ta[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
        ta[i].addEventListener("input", oninput, false);
    }
}
```

Why does the conversion happen， it's one of the quirks of javascript [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

`oninput = ...` has no scope, in non-strict mode it is scoped to the window, it will be like `window.oninput = xxx`

Sorry my bad englist